# How to get Firewall and Antivirus Status with WinAPI (NOT WMI)

Tags: c++, winapi

How to get Firewall and Antivirus Status in C++ using WinAPI (**NOT WMI**)?

Answer (score 3):

in vista+ this can be done with [WscGetSecurityProviderHealth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432506(v=vs.85).aspx).

example:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <Wscapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Wscapi.lib")
using namespace std;

string printStatus(WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_HEALTH status)
{
    switch (status)
    {
    case WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_HEALTH_GOOD: return "GOOD";
    case WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_HEALTH_NOTMONITORED: return "NOTMONITORED";
    case WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_HEALTH_POOR: return "POOR";
    case WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_HEALTH_SNOOZE: return "SNOOZE";
    default: return "Status Error";
    }
}

void getHealth()
{
    WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_HEALTH health;
    if (S_OK == WscGetSecurityProviderHealth(WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_FIREWALL, &health))
        cout << "FIREWALL:          " << printStatus(health) << endl;
    if (S_OK == WscGetSecurityProviderHealth(WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_AUTOUPDATE_SETTINGS, &health))
        cout << "AUTOUPDATE:        " << printStatus(health) << endl;
    if (S_OK == WscGetSecurityProviderHealth(WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_ANTIVIRUS, &health))
        cout << "ANTIVIRUS:         " << printStatus(health) << endl;
    if (S_OK == WscGetSecurityProviderHealth(WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_ANTISPYWARE, &health))
        cout << "ANTISPYWARE:       " << printStatus(health) << endl;
    if (S_OK == WscGetSecurityProviderHealth(WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_INTERNET_SETTINGS, &health))
        cout << "INTERNET SETTINGS: " << printStatus(health) << endl;
    if (S_OK == WscGetSecurityProviderHealth(WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_USER_ACCOUNT_CONTROL, &health))
        cout << "UAC:               " << printStatus(health) << endl;
    if (S_OK == WscGetSecurityProviderHealth(WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_SERVICE, &health))
        cout << "SERVICE:           " << printStatus(health) << endl;
    if (S_OK == WscGetSecurityProviderHealth(WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_ALL, &health))
        cout << "ALL:               " << printStatus(health) << endl;

}

void main()
{
    getHealth();
}
```

Possible output:

```
FIREWALL:          POOR
AUTOUPDATE:        GOOD
ANTIVIRUS:         POOR
ANTISPYWARE:       POOR
INTERNET SETTINGS: GOOD
UAC:               GOOD
SERVICE:           GOOD
ALL:               POOR
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't very useful. Try to explain what you've done, link to some references for the APIs and so on.