# How to check antivirus status on windows machine

Tags: windows

I am trying to get the antivirus status on windows if its real time protection is ON/OFF. I have tried some power shell commands but that gives values for Windows Defender but when any anti virus is installed, then those values are not correct.

Are there any Windows Security Center APIs which I can use to retrieve the AV status?

`Get-MpComputerStatus | select AntivirusEnabled`

This only returns the windows defender status

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Firewall and Antivirus Status with WinAPI (NOT WMI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068320/how-to-get-firewall-and-antivirus-status-with-winapi-not-wmi)